# I am having an issue regarding accessing a docker container on my local host port 5091

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

docker run --name alpine-desktop --rm -d -p 5901:5901 -e VNC_PASSWORD=root snowdreamtech/alpine-desktop

I pulled this docker image and it runs on local host port 5901 but when I open the port on browser I get this message :

This page isn’t working
localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

any help would be appreciated [docker pulled image and container info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAbxq.png)
[docker pulled image from dockerhub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sldm.png)

Github link to the image:
https://github.com/snowdreamtech/alpine-desktop

Comment: Getting the same error. Looks like the image is broken.

Comment: @Turing85 no the image is working perfect we just needed to install a rdp server to access it via the port given